# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable error

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, statistics, numpy-ndarray

For each gene, I want to perform McNemar's test and then evaluate if the p-value > 0.05. I want to calculate the number of genes that pass the test.

My code raised `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable`.

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables import mcnemar
from statsmodels.stats.gof import chisquare_effectsize
from statsmodels.stats.power import GofChisquarePower 

def generate_gene_df(gene, n):

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
         {"Gene" : gene,
          "Cells": (f'Cell{x}' for x in range(1, n+1)),
          "Control": np.random.choice([1,0], p=[0.1, 0.9], size=n),
          "Experimental": np.random.choice([1,0], p=[0.1+0.1, 0.9-0.1], size=n)},
         orient='columns'
    )

    df = df.set_index(["Gene","Cells"])
    
    return df

table = pd.crosstab([df["Gene"], df["Cells"]], 
                    [df["Control"], df["Experimental"]]).to_numpy()

# List of simulated genes
gene_df_list = [generate_gene_df(gene, n) for gene in gene_list]
df = pd.concat(gene_df_list)
df = df.reset_index()

alpha=0.05
p_adjusted=[]
pass_test = []

# McNemar's test
result = mcnemar(table, exact=True)

# Bonferroni correction
p_adjusted = multipletests(result.pvalue, alpha=alpha, method="bonferroni")

for index, value in np.ndenumerate(table):
    if result.pvalue > alpha:
        np.append(pass_test, result.pvalue[index])
    
num_passed = len(pass_test)
print("Number of genes that failed to reject H0 is: %i" %num_passed)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_593/1521754442.py in <module>
     11 for index, value in np.ndenumerate(table):
     12     if result.pvalue > alpha:
---> 13         np.append(pass_test, result.pvalue[index])
     14 
     15 

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Comment: It looks like your p-value is a scalar (a single number), not an array, so you cannot index into it.  (Your code currently does not run for other reasons, like undefined `gene_list`.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at `mcnemar`, so don't know what it produces. But the error tells us/youthat `result.pvalue` is a scalar value, and not indexable.

```
if result.pvalue > alpha:
   np.append(pass_test, result.pvalue[index])
```

I also can deduce that from the fact that the `if` line works.  It would return an `ambiguity error` if `result.pvalue` was an array.

Besides rereading the `mcnemar` docs, I'd suggest rereading the `np.append` docs (assuming you even did that!).

Generally we discourage use of `np.append` in a loop.  **np.append is not a list append clone**